# how to get max value in spark rdd and remove it?

Tags: apache-spark

there is a RDD object:

```
//have some data in RDD[(Int, Int)] object
(1, 2)
(3, 2)
(2, 3)
(5, 4)
(2, 7)
(5, 2)
(5, 7)
```

I want to get max key and remove it, the max key is 5, so the result I want is:

```
//a new RDD object,RDD[(Int, Int)]
(1, 2)
(3, 2)
(2, 3)
(2, 7)
```

Could you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first get the results sorted and then use `RDD.max()` to get the highest value and finally perform `filter` to filter the keys which are other than the highest key.

or

You can also register this as `DataFrame` and execute simple SQL query to get the results.

Comment: you don't need to sort the RDD before using `max`

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk - Thanks for correcting. You are right we do not need any sorting while using max. Sorting is implicitly performed in `max`.

Comment: actually no, sorting isn't performed anywhere as it's not necessary and slower (nlogn in the best case). You can simply reduce the whole RDD using an ordering function which is linear

Comment: @Sumit can i use _max()_ function in spark streaming?

Comment: `max()` is available with RDD API, so in Streaming You need to perform `Dstream.foreachRDD` and then for each RDD you can use `max` function.

Comment: @Sumit why is there sorting in _max()_ function? The sorting is quite performance hungry. As for me, I will define a variable to store max value, like this:   <br/> `val max1 = 0`   <br/> and use max1 compared with all elements and replace the value of max1 constantly until last element.

Comment: Actually there is no sorting. It is reduce  function applied to get the max value. Sorry if you confused it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's helpful to me.